# Why does it get the single bit like that?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I am looking some part of code that is supposed to get a single bit from an int.
It is as follows:

```
private int getBit( int token, int pos){  
   return ( token & ( 1 << pos ) ) != 0 ? 1 : 0;   
}
```

My question is why doesn't it do it the following (simpler) way?

```
return token & ( 1 << pos );
```

I expect that it will also return a `0` or `1`.
Am I wrong on this? Is the second (mine) version wrong?

Comment: The second version will return `1 << pos` in case the bit is set, or `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is wrong. When you execute

```
return token & ( 1 << pos );
```

if it is non-zero, then you get an int with every bit except the `pos` bit zeroed out, because that is the number on the right side of the `&` operator. This obviously would only be 1 if `pos==0`.

This happens because the `&` operator simply takes the bitwise and operation between corresponding bits in the two `int`s. Since `1 << pos` has a `1` bit in a position besides the lowest and `token` can presumably be any `int`, the result can also have a `1` bit in a position other than the lowest, making it greater than `1`.

Comment: An alternate way that avoids the branch but works: `return (token >>> pos) & 1`.

Comment: That's true. If you want to change less of the existing code you could also do `(token & ( 1 << pos )) && 1`. I didn't mention that stuff because that's not what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

Your version does not return the value of the bit at position pos. It returns the value 0 or 2^(pos-1).

Answer (score 2):

Your version returns 0 or `1<<pos`.

That won't matter if it is used in boolean context. But it might otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can use something on the order of

```
(token >> pos) & 1
```